# How to prevent echoing same value twice in php

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu

So I have this drop down list in my form which pull "tags" from database as value for drop down options:

```
<select name="cartags">
   <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID > '0'");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      echo "<option value=\""; echo $row['Tag']; echo "\""; echo ">"; echo $row['Tag']; echo "</option>";
   } 
   ?>   
</select>
```

What is my problem? My problem is that I am adding a lot of products into my databas and my code make dropdown list with tags for all this producst even if they have same tag. So what I need is solution how to prevent that same tag appear twice in my drop down.

I am pretty new to PHP and this is my first question here so I really hope that I explained my problem well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of `WHERE ID > '0'`? If `ID` is an auto-increment then it will always be positive. If not, it should be.

Why are you using `mysql_fetch_array` and then only using the associative keys? You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.

Why are you using a new `echo` every time you want to output a variable? Just concatenate.

Why are you setting the same string in `value` as the option's text? Without a value, it defaults to the text anyway.

Why are you not using backticks around your column and table names?

Try this instead:

```
<select name="cartags">
<?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `Tag` FROM `Products`");
  while(list($tag) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
      echo "<option>".$tag."</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: In my opinion backticks are ugly because you only need them when you use reserved keywords

Comment: So you're happy with something like this? ``SELECT id, name, `timestamp` FROM `table` ``

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question + pointing on my mistakes. Well, I am php noob and some stuff I am learning in wrong way, this is answer to all yours "Why are you..." question.

Thanks again, drink one virtual beer on my account (B).

Comment: Yes, or better use diffent column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="cartags">
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT Tag, COUNT(Tag) tg Products WHERE ID > '0'  GROUP BY Tag HAVING COUNT(Tag)>0 ORDER BY tg DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<option value=\""; echo $row['tg']; echo "\""; echo ">"; echo $row['tg']; echo " </option>";
 } 
?>   
</select>
```

It will also display the top tags that have the most first.

Comment: Thank you, I will test this out too. Probably this will help me in further work on this. Cheers!